# Search repo at commit/tag/branch

Tags: github

I am looking for a way to achieve code searches for specific repo state. It can be a specific commit, tag, or, branch.

Does github's current search feature provide some way to do this?

Currently I clone the project in a repl.it bash shell and then do a find/grep on the file system. Hoping there is a better alternative here.